# How to get the value of multiple checkbox within a while loop before submission using php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I'm new to `php` and have encountered some problems with `checkbox` within a while loop.
I want to add checkbox to each row of a table and check if they are checked. However, the table is a result of a query and the number of output is not sure. So I want to use a while loop to get the value of each output and pass the `$_SESSION['n']`, and the value of each `checkbox` should also be linked to n; Then after the user check part of the boxes, those items are to be deleted. I have tried to do things like below but it didn't work. How can I add the `checkbox` and pass the value of each `checkbox` within the loop to next page?

```
<html>
  <head><title>ResultCheckUpdateAsset</title></head>
  <body>
  <form method="post" action="Delete Items.php">

<?php    
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1) ;

print"
<table border=3> 
<tr>
<td><input type='checkbox' name='selectAll' value='Y' checked>Select All</td>
<th>Assets number</td>
<th>Serial number</td>
<tr>";

session_start();

$_SESSION['n'] = 0;
$n = $_SESSION['n'];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
  print "<input type='checkbox' name='check[$n]' value='Y' checked='checked'></td>";
  print "<th> $row[0] </td>";
  print "<th> $row[1] </td>";
  print "<tr>";     

  $_SESSION['n']++;
  //$_SESSION['check'.$_SESSION['n']] = (the value of check[$n])
  $_SESSION['assetNo'.$_SESSION['n']] = $row[0];
  $_SESSION['serialNo'.$_SESSION['n']] = $row[1];
    }
print "</table>";
print"<br>";
 ?>

<input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>

</body>
<html>
```

Comment: read about $_GET, $_POST, form and any book about HTML and PHP... :)

Comment: I am very confused can you elaborate it more better

Comment: if you just want to delete the checked rows, give checkbox name `check[]`..then the posted data, `$_POST['check']` will be an array which contains only checked checkbox values.. and if `Delete Items.php` is your filename, i'd suggest you to consider renaming it.. :)

Comment: @Mr.TK I'm aware of the use of $_GET and $_POST, but since I also need to pass the value of n, I'm not sure what is the name of each checkbox  since I always get "undefined variable" error when passing the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and inform. U got bad syntax on `HTML` and `PHP` (all basics)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>ResultCheckUpdateAsset</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="Delete Items.php">
    <?php
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
    ?>
    <table border=3>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='checkbox' name='selectAll' value='Y' checked>Select All</td>
            <th>Assets number</th>
            <th>Serial number</th>
        <tr>
            <?php session_start();

            $_SESSION['n'] = 0;
            $n = $_SESSION['n'];

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) { ?>
            <td><input type='checkbox' name='check[<?= $n ?>]' value='Y' checked='checked'></td>
            <th><?= $row[0] ?></th>
            <th><?= $row[1] ?></th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $_SESSION['n']++;
        //$_SESSION['check'.$_SESSION['n']] = (the value of check[$n])
        $_SESSION['assetNo' . $_SESSION['n']] = $row[0];
        $_SESSION['serialNo' . $_SESSION['n']] = $row[1];
        $n++;
        } ?>
    </table>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I only know little about html and php and I basically googled all...I've tried it but how to pass the value of checkbox to the next page?

Comment: On `Delete Items.php` (u should rename the file) use `$_REQUEST` to get the values of your form. Check your inputs `name=` to get the proper values.